# Как вернуть строки из DataFrame, в которых в колонке присутствует скобки?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных

Необходимо создать функцию, возвращающую DataFrame со строками, в которых в выбранной колонке `J` с комментарием присутствовали скобки:

Eсли скобки в ячейке есть, то берем всю строку и добавляем в новый DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'Остальное':['Цена', 'Производство', 'Комментарии', 'Цена', 'Производство', 'Комментарии', 'Цена', 'Производство', 'Комментарии'],

'J':['0', '0', 'нет', '32', '2', '(куплено)', '452', '5', 'купленный (тов)'],

'Адрес':['Delhi', 'Delhi', 'Delhi', 'Kannauj', 'Kannauj', 'Kannauj', 'Angeles', 'Angeles', 'Angeles']
})
```

Должно получиться:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame({'Остальное':[ 'Комментарии', 'Комментарии'],

'J':[ '(куплено)', 'купленный (тов)'],

'Адрес':[ 'Kannauj', 'Angeles']
})
```

*Желательно, чтобы индексы добавленных строк сохранились с прежнего DataFrame.*

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = data.loc[data['J'].str.contains(r'\(.*\)')]
```